# How to find out the generic type passed to the parent

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection

Tell me please how you can determine the type that was passed to the parameter generics during inheritance

```
public abstract class BaseEntity 
{
}

public class DogEntity : BaseEntity
{
}

public interface IAnimal
{
}

public abstract class Animal<TEntity> : IAnimal
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
}

public class Dog : Animal<DogEntity>
{
}
```

I have only Dog entity type, I need to get DogEntity

```
Type type = typeof(Dog);
```

I would be grateful for any help or hint

Comment: `typeof(Dog).BaseType.GenericTypeArguments[0];` maybe does it, I'm on mobile though so can't test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using reflection

```
Type type = typeof(Dog)
    .BaseType
    .GetGenericArguments()
    .Single();
```

Comment: But what if I have inheritance from Dog, for example `class BigDog: Dog`? How to get to the entity `Animal<T>` in another way, not through recursion and `.BaseType` validation?

Comment: @АлексейДобров This is starting to sound like an XY problem. Why do you need to use reflection to get the type?

Comment: Yes, I should use recursion and not worry about it

Comment: @АлексейДобров As I said In my answer: If you ever need to "figure out" the type with Generics at runtime, you are jsut reinventing Overriding. And as with most people that reinvent the wheel, it is worse then the original.

Answer (score 0):

Dog to Animal are the classical cases for Inheritance, Polymorphy - not generics. Right up there with Shape/Circle/Sphere. It should be `DogEntity : AnimalEntity` and `AnimalEntity : BaseEntity`. This inheritance chain really makes no sense.

The **whole point** of generics is that you can put in just about any type and still have **compile time** type checks. You never have to check the types, the compiler does it for you.

If you ever wonder about the type with generics with 90% propability you do not have a generics scenario. You are most propably reinventing overriding. I see people often gravitate towards generics + type checks in error, when plain old Polymorphy/Overriding would be the answer. It is propably one of the most common example of a XY Problem in our day and age.

Comment: I gave a very abstract example to the account of `Dog` and `DogEntity`, so through inheritance I can not solve the problem. In my case, I create a layer between `IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` and my `EntityConfiguration`. At runtime, when saving, I need to fill in the shadow property, only for those `TEntity` that have this configured in `EntityConfiguration`

Comment: @АлексейДобров Different behaviors for different implementations. That is quite literally what Overriding was invented for. | As I said, using `typof()` or `is` checks with generics when you should have used plain old Overriding - this is a exceedingly common XY Problem case these days. | "At runtime, when saving, I need to fill in the shadow property, only for those" a get-only bool property `HasShadowProperty`. And a exception thrown out of the `ShadowProperty` setter, if that one is false. All you would need for the described behavior.

Comment: I am doing an override of the `SaveChanges` method, for processing inside `ChangeTracker.Entries`. At this point, I check which `ShadowProperty` has been included in the `EntityConfiguration` (by assigning true / false), for a specific `TEntity`. This is where finding the right `EntityConfiguration<TEntity>` is required. If this can be done easier, I will be grateful for the help